# uri-encode-permitted chars not working

Tags: codeigniter

chapterdetails/5/My4wIFRoZSBUaGlyZCBMZXR0ZXIgZnJvbSBMb3JkIEdhbmVzaGE=

this giving error  The URI you submitted has disallowed characters.

config.php  settings
$config['permitted_uri_chars'] = ''

Answer (score 0):

Codeigniter is not allow the character = in its URL by default
So you have two options

1. First is removing the charter from URL or
2. Second is change the configs in `config.php`  like below

   `$config['permitted_uri_chars'] = 'a-z 0-9~%.:_\-=';`

Note:Before changing the default configuration in permitted uri characters check if it may lead to any problems like security vulnerability etc